# WORDPRESS - include CSS in functions.php doesnt work

Tags: wordpress

I need to include some external css files, i use this snippet in functions.php but neither of them works.. Why..?

```
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'add_css' );

function add_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
}
```

I'm using Twenty-Twenty-One child theme
This is my style.css

```
/*Theme Name: Twenty Twenty-One Child
    Theme URI: https://wordpress.org/themes/twentytwentyone/
    Template: twentytwentyone
    Author: the WordPress team
    Author URI: https://wordpress.org/
    */
h2{
    color:red!important;
} */
```

h2 is to see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using a child theme, you want to use `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` instead of `get_template_directory_uri` - Unless the stylesheets are part of the parent theme.

```
function add_css() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/assets/css/bootstrap.css' );
}
```

Comment: It dosnt work, i  appreciate this, maybe  I will use it in the future

Comment: Where are you putting the files, with respect to your directory structure?  Also, is style.css the Child Style or the parent style? Please clarify.

Comment: In wp-content/themes/ i have: twentytwentyone (original theme) and my child theme - twentytwentyone-child.
i create style css following the instruction of wordpress.org that you can see up. Then i focus on functions.php but it doesnt work. 
" is style.css the Child Style or the parent style?" ... Sincerely i dont know.

Comment: Is the bootstrap.css getting added?

Comment: No.. I really don't uderstand. I try also with a plug-in to automatize it but nothing...

Comment: If i dont create a new index.php (in my child theme) i can see old style ( parent theme) with my new css style ( h2.red). If i create a new index.php and add <h2>hello world</h2> the style disappear.

Comment: You started another question?

Comment: Yes, i understood where was the mistake. I did everyrhing well but i dont "inizialize" my index.php. it needs get_header and get_footer to work!...

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your parent theme loads it's styles your function will vary. You can check the [Enqueue stylesheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet) section in the Theme handbook for more clarification. Below is their example if the parent theme loads its style using a function starting with `get_stylesheet`

Make sure you are using the correct parent handle, 'parent-style' is used for TwentyFifteen theme for example.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {
    $parenthandle = 'parent-style'; // This is 'twentyfifteen-style' for the Twenty Fifteen theme.
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    wp_enqueue_style( $parenthandle, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css', 
        array(),  // if the parent theme code has a dependency, copy it to here
        $theme->parent()->get('Version')
    );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style', get_stylesheet_uri(),
        array( $parenthandle ),
        $theme->get('Version') // this only works if you have Version in the style header
    );
}
```

You should also look at the [wp_enqueue_style](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) code reference as the handle for your bootstrap style should probably not be `style` as it needs to be unique e.g. `bootstrap-style`

Comment: I try it with  $parenthandle = ' twenty-twenty-one-style ' but doesnt work. I add in the question my style.css maybe there is something wrong in..